# Search events of user via FQL

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I wanted to find events attended by my user, but somehow fql is not working without providing event id. Anyone knows why ?

`SELECT rsvp_status FROM event_member WHERE uid = int_user_uid`

link : http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/fql.query

Answer (score 2):

From [Facebook Query Language (FQL) - Facebook Developers](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/)

> Queries are of the form SELECT [fields] FROM [table] WHERE [conditions]. Unlike SQL, the FQL FROM clause can contain only a single table. You can use the IN keyword in SELECT or WHERE clauses to do subqueries, but the subqueries cannot reference variables in the outer query's scope. Your query must also be indexable, meaning that it queries properties that are marked as indexable in the documentation below.

ie all FQL queries require at least one indexable column in the WHERE clause.

And, as you can see from the [FQL event table page](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/event/) the only indexable property is eid.